# Micro Focus Visual Cobol for Eclipse Installing

Tags: eclipse, cobol, cobol85

I'm in a new cobol project. My customer request us using an IDE which integrated Micro focus Visual Cobol (can connect to oracle's Pro*cobol). I have found 2 version of that.

Micro focus Visual Cobol for Visual Studio
Micro focus Visual Cobol for Eclipse
My team has good experience with eclipse, so I was chose Micro focus Visual Cobol for Eclipse.

I have done any follow document of Micro focus page http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.visualcobol.eclipsewin%2FGUID-9BF8F107-22F3-414D-BFFE-D242947A7B79.html

However, when I installed done. I open up and the COBOL perspective cannot showing. I have try to open a sample cobol project created by micro focus, and project cannot start.

I'm going to upload some images, but stackoverflow warns me "have at least 10 reputation to upload image". Please help me... thanks you very much

Comment: what errors you get ?

Comment: hi,you when I start visual cobol for eclipse, and I want to create a project, coding... I have to open COBOL perspective, but when I go to window -> Open perspective, I cannot see COBOL perspective. It has to be there follow micro focus documentation. I don't understand what happens???